# Cusps of parallel/offset curves

Tags: differential-geometry

Found this remark in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve

When parallel curves are constructed they will have cusps when the distance from the curve matches the radius of curvature. These are the points where the curve touches the evolute.

I would like to prove it, or at least have a better explanation of why this happens.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: **HINT**: Differentiate the function $\beta(s) = \alpha(s) + rN(s)$, where $\alpha$ is arclength-parametrized and $N$ is the unit normal.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Thanks for the answer! I did just that and even proved that the curvature of $\beta$ is $\kappa_\beta = \frac{\kappa_\alpha}{1-r\kappa_\alpha}$ but I don't know how I should approach the next step!

Comment: @TedShifrin and going with that I also got that $R_\beta = R_\alpha - r$ where $R$ is the radius of curvature

Comment: No, the point is that $\beta'(s)=0$ when $r=1/\kappa(s)$. I would recommend you use the local canonical form for $\alpha$ (assuming $s=0$ when this happens) to write down the local form of $\beta$. (See, for example, p. 17 of my differential geometry text, linked for free in my profile.)

Comment: You can use the local canonical form directly to get parametric equations for $\beta(s)$ and see the cusp!

Comment: Ok! I deleted the comments since I had made an error in a calculation.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for your help! and your wonderful papers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't recall seeing this question on this site before and because it may be of interest to other people, I'm going to sketch the computation to which I alluded in the comments.

Let's consider the parallel curve $\beta(s)=\alpha(s)+rN(s)$ with $r=1/\kappa_0$ (here the subscript denotes the value at $s=0$). The local canonical form (see, e.g., p. 17 of [my text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf)) for $\alpha$ at $s=0$ is
$$\alpha(s)=\big(s-\tfrac16\kappa_0^2s^3 + o(s^3)\big)T_0 + \big(\tfrac12\kappa_0s^2 + \tfrac16\kappa'_0s^3 + o(s^3)\big)N_0.$$
Differentiating, we see that
$$\alpha''(s) = \kappa(s)N(s) = \big({-}\kappa_0^2s + o(s)\big)T_0+\big(\kappa_0 + \kappa'_0s + o(s)\big)N_0,$$
and so
$$\frac1{\kappa_0}N(s) = \frac{\big({-}s+o(s)\big)T_0 + \big(\frac1{\kappa_0}+\frac{\kappa'_0}{\kappa_0^2}s+o(s)\big)N_0}{\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{\kappa'_0}{\kappa_0}s\right)^2+\kappa_0^2s^2+o(s^2)}}.$$
Using the usual first-order approximation  $\frac1{\sqrt{1+x}}\approx 1-\frac12x$, we work out that
$$\beta(s) = \big({-}\tfrac16\kappa_0s^3+O(s^3)\big)T_0 + \big(\tfrac1{\kappa_0} + \tfrac12\kappa_0 s^2 + O(s^2)\big)N_0.$$
This makes it clear that $\beta$ has a cusp at the point $\frac1{\kappa_0}N_0$.

Comment: Could you explain how using the first order approximation there leads to that conclusion about $\beta$ I've been trying to understand it for a bit but I can't see it.

Comment: Perfect! And do we disregard the square denominator for the $T_0$ term?

Comment: So you replace $1/\sqrt{1+as+bs^2+o(s^2)}$ by $1-\frac12(as+bs^2) + O(s^2)$; look what happens when you multiply the coefficient of $N_0$ by this.

Comment: Well, look at the $T_0$ term. You'll get higher-order terms, right?

Comment: Right! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. When you're satisfied with the answer, you should accept it. :)